# Add the index of list to bind_rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have this data:

```
dat=list(structure(list(Group.1 = structure(3:4, .Label = c("A","B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), class = "factor"), Pr1 = c(65, 75)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame"),NULL, structure(list( Group.1 = structure(3:4, .Label = c("A","B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), class = "factor"), Pr1 = c(81,4)), row.names = c(NA,-2L), class = "data.frame"))
```

I want to use combine using   `bind_rows(dat)` but keeping the index number as a varaible
Output Include `Type([[1]]  and [[3]])`

```
  type   Group.1     Pr1
1   1      C          65
2   1      D         75
3   3      C         81
4   3      D          4
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**data.table solution**

use `rbindlist()` from the `data.table`-package, which had built-in id-support that respects NULL df's.

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist( dat, idcol = TRUE )

   .id Group.1 Pr1
1:   1       C  65
2:   1       D  75
3:   3       C  81
4:   3       D   4
```

**dplyr - partly solution**

bind_rows also has ID-support, but it 'skips' empty elements...

```
bind_rows( dat, .id = "id" )

  id Group.1 Pr1
1  1       C  65
2  1       D  75
3  2       C  81
4  2       D   4
```

Note that the ID of the third element from dat becomes 2, and not 3.

Comment: `bind_rows(setNames(dat, seq_along(dat)), .id = "id")` for no skipping.

Answer (score 6):

According to the documentation of `bind_rows()` you can supply the name for `.id` argument of the function. When you apply `bind_rows()` to the list of `data.frame`s the names of the list containing your `data.frame`s are assigned to the identifier column. [EDIT] But there is a problem mentioned by @Wimpel:

```
names(dat)
NULL
```

However, supplying the names to the list will do the thing:

```
names(dat) <- 1:length(dat)
names(dat)
[1] "1" "2" "3"
bind_rows(dat, .id = "type")
  type Group.1 Pr1
1    1       C  65
2    1       D  75
3    3       C  81
4    3       D   4
```

Or in one line, if you prefer:

```
bind_rows(setNames(dat, seq_along(dat)), .id = "type")
```